# How to calculate size of a specific cavity in a protein for every frame in trajectory file?

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

Here is the situation, I have trajecory file of a protein of interest. That protein has 2 main cavities that are participating in interraction with ligands or other proteins and also other cavities. Also residue numbers around this cavity are more or less known. I'm looking for a method or software to get volume of this cavities for every frame in trajectory.

I want to specify a cavity around a residue and  get output for this cavity. What I am looking for is something like this:

```
Frame Cavity volume
1 1500 A^3
2 1499 A^3
3 1499 A^3
4 1499 A^3
5 1498 A^3
```

I tried CASTp, it was okey for singe frame if wrote it as pdb but not promising for a 100ns trajectory.

Also tried CAVER. CAVER was able to open a trajectory file and calculate cavity volumes for the frame that I chose but it was not possible to calculate cavity volumes for all of the frames and get output from it.

If anyone has any suggestion I'll be greatful.

Comment: If you can get one, then you can get many - it's just a matter of making right scripts for sequential initiation of program an gathering the output.

Comment: @Mithoron Well I gladly would do that but It has graphical user interface so I dont know how can I do that.  Also that program has problematic naming for cavities, for different frames same cavity has different names. If someone confirms it is possible with this software,then I'll dig for a solution.

Comment: @OnurOzcan CASTp seems to operate as a standalone webserver at which you have to submit your data, so it doesn't sound like a good solution. On the other hand the CAVER program seems to allow for analysis of a series of frames, see the examples that come with the program

Comment: They both provide pymol plugins, but the CASTp plugin is for visualization only. It may be possible to interact with the CAVER plugin using python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, POVME exactly does this.